# Poster of the week on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, users

Why doesn't [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) have `Poster of the week` system for corresponding tags?

I mean for a particular tag it should have `Poster of the week` system. Any specific reason why such system is not incorporated there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [stats pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=stats&pagesize=50) for the tags?

It doesn't have a weekly breakdown but shows the top askers and answerers for the last 30 days in that tag. (along with the all time top 20)

Comment: The rep for the top poster in that tag looks wayyyyy off

Comment: What happened to Neil Butterworth's account?

Comment: nb69307? Is that Neil?

Comment: Yes..what happened to his reputation score?

Comment: Who knows? The profile says "please delete me" so draw your own conclusions!